# VMware NOT_IMPLEMENTED pollDefault

Tags: vmware

I have VMware Workstation and Windows 10. When I'm working in VM, I can have an error message like this:

```
VMware Workstation unrecoverable error: (vthread-8) NOT_IMPLEMENTED bora\lib\pollDefault\pollDefault.c:3914 A log file is available in "...path_to_log...\vmware-ui-10708.1og". You can request support. 
    To collect data to submit to VMware support, choose "Collect Support Data" from the Help menu. You can also run the "vm-support" script in the Workstation folder directly. We will respond on the basis of your support entitlement.
```

It doesn't matter what VM and what am I doing - this can happen to every VM and even it is paused. The error appears with different delays after starting VMware. If I minimize the error and don't minimize VM them I can work further. If I do so, after some time I have the second message and so on... If I minimize the VM window while I have this error then after maximizing it VM hangs. But if i click or type something then I won't see it but after recovery after error I see, that clicks were done and typing was ok. So, when I have the error then the best way is to save everything in VM, click OK in error window and then to pause the VM in tray. Afrer that I stop the VM, go into VM folder, delete lock folders and start the VM again. I must do that because the VM is locked (VM in use) after this error. It is very annoying and it's difficult to work with it. Tried to google it but nothing found. Only the similar problem with pollDefault but another error and codeline in source - the solution didn't help.

What can I do?

Thank you.

EDIT:

That log is in file:

```
2016-02-21T15:01:06.737+03:00| vthread-5| I125: POLL could not signal socket thread (fd 728, ret -1, err 10053)
2016-02-21T15:01:06.737+03:00| vmui| I125: SOCKET 2 (2400) recv error 10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2016-02-21T15:01:06.740+03:00| vthread-8| W115: POLL Failed to read from the signal socket 1704, return -1, error 10054/An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2016-02-21T15:01:06.740+03:00| vmui| I125: Detected automation socket close for VM

2016-02-21T15:01:06.740+03:00| vmui| I125: POLL could not signal socket thread (fd 728, ret -1, err 10053)
2016-02-21T15:01:06.740+03:00| vthread-8| W115: POLL Failed to read from the signal socket 1704, return -1, error 10054/An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2016-02-21T15:01:06.740+03:00| vthread-8| W115: POLL Failed to read from the signal socket 1704, return -1, error 10054/An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2016-02-21T15:01:06.740+03:00| vthread-8| W115: POLL Failed to read from the signal socket 1704, return -1, error 10054/An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2016-02-21T15:01:06.740+03:00| vthread-8| W115: POLL Failed to read from the signal socket 1704, return -1, error 10054/An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2016-02-21T15:01:06.740+03:00| vthread-8| W115: POLL Failed to read from the signal socket 1704, return -1, error 10054/An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2016-02-21T15:01:06.740+03:00| vthread-8| W115: POLL Failed to read from the signal socket 1704, return -1, error 10054/An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2016-02-21T15:01:06.740+03:00| vthread-8| W115: POLL Failed to read from the signal socket 1704, return -1, error 10054/An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2016-02-21T15:01:06.740+03:00| vthread-8| W115: POLL Failed to read from the signal socket 1704, return -1, error 10054/An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2016-02-21T15:01:06.740+03:00| vthread-8| W115: POLL Failed to read from the signal socket 1704, return -1, error 10054/An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2016-02-21T15:01:06.740+03:00| vthread-8| W115: POLL Failed to read from the signal socket 1704, return -1, error 10054/An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2016-02-21T15:01:06.740+03:00| vthread-8| W115: POLL Failed to read from the signal socket 1704, return -1, error 10054/An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2016-02-21T15:01:06.740+03:00| vthread-8| W115: POLL Failed to read from the signal socket 1704, return -1, error 10054/An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Answer (score 1):

I have VMware Workstation 12 running on Windows 10 Pro, with 3 virtual machines and different SO.
Sometimes the VMware has the same behavior described by you and I do the same workaround, I found no solution both in VMware and web.

Answer (score 0):

Better workaround :
clic OK on popup, then go to your virtual machine directory.
Delete "*.lck" folders, BUT NOT "*vmem.lck" folder.
start back VMware and your virtual machine. It will be in the state when you closed the popup.

dFx